# Java Mongodb match regex to any document field

Tags: java, regex, mongodb

I have some documents like this.

```
{
    _id: "1234",
    code:"asdf",
    text:"aas23423",
    ....
{
```

I need to do a regex search on every value in my db. Is there a way to do something like the following?

```java
public List<Document> findWithRegex(MongoCollection<Document> collection, String regex){
        Document findQuery = new Document();
        findQuery.append(/*any key in any document*/, Pattern.compile(regex));
        FindIterable<Document> iterable = collection.find(findQuery);
}
```

Or if that is not possible is there a way to `||` something like this together. Something like this.

`collection.find(document -> document.code.matches(regex-pattern) || document.text.matches(regex-pattern))`

Comment: Would be helpful to know what your method is trying to achieve in greater detail. Maybe you can edit it with comments for what each line is doing?

Comment: @DennisKozevnikoff I give it a collection and a regex pattern. I expect a List of Documents back where any field in that document has matched that regex pattern. The code was just for an example of how it works on a single field (the example works for a single field), I need any field.

Comment: If it works for one field and you want to do it for all other fields you just need to create a loop and loop through all the elements.

Comment: Obviously I can do that but the runtime of that is terrible considering behind all of those `find` calls is a network request. If I can specify what I want in one call that is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Create another field which contains a concatenation of values from the existing fields, search that field.

If the fields are large, create another collection where documents have just the field used for the text search.

You should likely be using [text search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/) instead of regular expression queries.